# Module properties storing procs?

Tags: ruby, lambda

I'm essentially trying to do this

```
module Foo
  @@do_something = Proc.new { puts "something" }
end

Foo::do_something.()
```

The properties need to be procs/lambdas so that they can be passed as arguments to another proc/lambda/method:

```
def other_method(do_something)
  do_something.()
end

other_method(Foo::do_something)
```

Currently this is working:

```
module Foo
  DO_SOMETHING = Proc.new { puts "something" }
end

Foo::DO_SOMETHING.()
```

But I'm guessing this won't pass code review. Is this the only way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could simply create an accessor for the class variable:

```
module Foo
  def self.do_something
    @@do_something  
  end
  @@do_something = Proc.new { puts "something" }
end

Foo::do_something.()
something
```

or any of the following:

```
Foo::do_something[]
Foo::do_something.call
Foo::do_something.yield
```

Comment: I have quite a few of these procs so my concern is the number of properties and accessor methods. I suppose I could return the proc directly from self.do_something instead of storing it in @@do_something and returning that?

Comment: You might consider storing them in a hash, to be returned by a module function that takes a key as an argument. I used the class variable only because you did, gritting my teeth as I did so.

Comment: That solution make more sense and much more scalable.